# Flux bufferMillis - How to test?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to test `Flux.bufferMillis` by using virtual scheduler but it seems intermittently failed.
Following is the code to

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(new Supplier() {
    Flux get() {
        return Flux.interval(1 second).take(5).bufferMillis(1500);
    }}
)
    .thenAwait(5 seconds)
    .expectNext(...)
    .verifyComplete();
```

The error I intermittently get is as follow:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextMatches" failed (expected: onNext(); actual: onError(java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable))
```

I'm not sure why Scheduler is unavailable occasionally.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in a JUnit test in reactor, either on master or on 3.0.4.RELEASE tag... Is that the full extent of your test? Any other test executed in the same run? This happens if the `VirtualTimeScheduler` has been `dispose()` (or equivalent deprecated `shutdown`)

Comment: That mostly happens if the test is run by gradle along with other tests.

Comment: You can check the whole tests at https://github.com/sinwe/reactor-core-scala in master branch. It is breaking now

Comment: I think that is due to `scalatest` default behavior of parallelising the tests (see https://github.com/maiflai/gradle-scalatest#parallel-testing). StepVerifier's virtual time depends on a SchedulerFactory being set sequentially, not in parallel. Can you try without test parallelism, just to be sure?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But this is intermittent, so I have to run it multiple times to be sure that it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StepVerifier` and virtual time work roughly this way when you just provide the `Supplier<Flux>` and `verify()` it:

1. `StepVerifier` obtains a "virtual time scheduler" instance.
2. It replaces the core's `SchedulerFactory` with one that will return that virtual time scheduler to all operators that need a default scheduler.
3. It calls the supplier to create the operator chain to test, and subscribes to it, then plays and verify the scenario.
4. Finally, it cleans up and shuts down the virtual scheduler it used.

That's where there can be a problem when running tests in parallel: since there is only 1 factory, and due to the way the VTS is obtained, having 2 parallel virtual time tests can lead to using the same `VirtualTimeScheduler` instance in the background. So the first test will shutdown the scheduler and the second test will be `REJECTED`.

Since `gradle-scalatest` [runs in parallel by default](https://github.com/maiflai/gradle-scalatest#parallel-testing), this is most likely the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer. However, improvement can be made such that the Scheduler should only shutdown when there is no reference to it anymore.

Comment: It doesn't seems setting parallelism to 1 fix the issue. The thing still happening. It is passing in my local machine but not in CI.

Comment: ok, there is something else going on then... we need more info (test failure stacktrace) and best to manage to reproduce it locally. Can you open an issue in reactor-addons' github and try to collect the stacktrace?

Comment: wait, in your last TravisCI failing build you have a run of tests that is fine, then a run of `scoverage` which fails... You didn't configure SCoverage to run sequentially, so most likely it is still the same issue. see https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage/issues/32#issuecomment-69922795 to prevent parallelism

Comment: I thought configuring test {maxParallelFork = 1} will work both for test and scoverage... I'll have a look

Comment: You're probably right, `testScoverage {  maxParallelForks = 1} ` is probably what I need

Comment: we'll experiment with adding reference counting to VirtualTimeScheduler and/or streamline the StepVerifier + VTS experience though, that suggestion had a good potential ;)

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that the `testScoverage {maxParallelForks = 1}` fixed the build. Thank you for helping